# Как в HTML сделать так, чтобы слова переносились на следующую строку, а не уходили влево?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Интересует, как отформатировать текст, чтобы если он выходит за пределы страницы или своего блока, он автоматически переносился на другую строку, а то появляется полоса прокрутки снизу... Что можно сделать в HTML или CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такое CSS-свойство:

```
word-wrap break-word
```

Его укажите в свойствах блока, в котором расположено "вылезающее" содержимое.

Comment: Которое в css3 переименовали в `overflow-wrap`. Впрочем, старый вариант куда более кроссбраузерный на данный момент.

Comment: @Qwertiy, полезное замечание, к слову.